# Object-Oriented Way of Dealing with Read-Only User Input

Tags: python, oop, input, modeling

I'm making a simple command-line game but not sure how to model read-only user inputs in Python.

Right now, I'm thinking of declaring an ABC called `Input` and subclassing it:

```
import abc


class Input(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pop(self):
        pass


class NameInput(Input):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def pop(self):
        return self._name
```

Another way I came up with is using the `@property` decorator:

```
import abc


class Input(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class NameInput(Input):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @property
    def value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._name
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing my objective? If so, what is it?

For your information, my goal is not just building a program up and running but picking up good programming habits. Please feel free to overcomplicate and tell me the way you prefer (for the sake of scalability and maintainability) in a large-scale project.

Comment: You don't need that property, just make `value` an attribute. Or are you trying to make value not settable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `.pop()` is almost reserved for stacks. You shouldn't use that, as the behaviour you're doing here is different.

The `@property` is pretty good, but you're misusing it. It should be:

```
class NameInput(Input):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @property
    def value(self):
        return clean_data(self._name)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._name = value
```

The second `value` function is if you want to have your `value` property settable.

You can find more info there: [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

The property allows you to do some in-depth cleanup (like removing HTML injections, ...) either on input or output. I'm calling `clean_data()` for the sake of the example, there.

But maybe, depending on what your actual is, you may want to create your own descriptors, so that you can reuse them. That's what happens in ORMs, for instance. More info: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html

Like, in the django ORM (eg. http://www.effectivedjango.com/orm.html ), all these `models.CharField` and `models.XxxXxx` are descriptors. You may want to read more documentation (link above) or checking these projects' source code. You might find inspiration :-).

Good luck!

Comment: why should they use a setter? Maybe they don't want it to be settable. I totally agree about `pop`, btw.

Comment: As I mentioned, "if you want to have your `value` property settable". It doesn't mean the OP must always implement it. :)

Comment: Then in what sense were they misusing it?

Comment: The input parameters. For the getter, there should be only `self`.

Comment: Ah, totally missed that